# How to write Insert Query in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, insert-query

In Yii2 How to insert data from one table to another table.

Here i have two tables `table1` and `table2`.

Now what i need is when a condition met i need transfer a specific data from `table1` to `table2`.

so help to write insert Query for this scenario in Yii2

This is the insert query given in yii2 docs

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
->insert('user', [
'name' => 'Sam',
'age' => 30,
])->execute();
```

But i need this Query to be convert according Yii2 Query

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers;
```

Answer (score 3):

`QueryBuilder`'s `insert` method returns this:

```
return 'INSERT INTO ' . $schema->quoteTableName($table)
    . ' (' . implode(', ', $names) . ') VALUES ('
    . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ')';
```

So there is no way to specify `SELECT` here.

Can't find it in core, I thinks it's not implemented because it's pretty rare case.

You can use your custom SQL code like this:

```
$sql = '...';

\Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

**Useful links:**

- [QueryBuilder insert()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querybuilder.html#insert%28%29-detail)
- [Connection createCommand()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#createCommand%28%29-detail)
- [INSERT INTO SELECT syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

**P.S.** I also reported issue [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8293), so maybe it will be added to the core in the future. If you want it now for repeated usage, you can implement such method by yourself.

Comment: I can't understand help me to write for these two tables                 **table1** name,status,problem,text                                               **table2** name,status,problem,text

Comment: What exactly you can't understand?

Comment: Mentioned query for converting doesn't contain `table1`. Correct SQL according to your needs and use the method I described in answer.

Comment: where i can give table1 name, table2 name  and columns name belongs to each

Comment: As I said, correct SQL query. Question doesn't contain any information about `table1` and `table2` except their names. And your example is not even related with these tables.

Comment: sorry for saying this again really I can't understand help me to write for these two tables table1name: **Claim** columns: **name,status,problem,text**,  table2name: **pending** columns: **name,status,problem,text** , here how can i insert data from claim table to pending table

Comment: How can i write Query for this

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest versions of YII2 (> 2.0.11), it is possible to do this.

Create a sub query, and pass it to the insert method of the DB object.

This will generate an INSERT INTO ... SELECT

eg.

```
$query = (new Query())
    ->select([
        'CustomerName' => 'SupplierName',
        'Country' => 'Country'
    ])
    ->from('Suppliers');

Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
    ->insert('Customers', $query)
    ->execute();
```